# Microsoft Edge bottom half cut off on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, browser, microsoft-edge

About a week or two ago, bottom half and part of right-side of Edge is now cut off on my Windows 10, Dell Precision 5520 laptop.

Chrome on same computers works ok.

After restart Windows, Edge works great for a day or two.

Laptop purchased 3 months ago.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following ways:

1. I suggest we clear the browsing history and check if the issue persist.

Please follow the steps:

Open Microsoft Edge.

Click on **“...”** (… symbol) on the top right corner of the browser.

Select **Settings** from the drop down menu.

Click on **Choose what to clear** under **Clear browsing data**.

Check the **Cookies** and saved website data (and any other data you want to clear) and click on **Clear** button.

2. Enable Inprivate Browing feature of Edge.

We can refer to [Enable Private Browsing in IE 11 and Microsoft Edge](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/internet-explorer-tips/use-private-browsing-ie-11-microsoft-edge/)

3. Try to reset Windows Edge. Go to **Settings->App->Apps and features->Windows Edge->Advanced options->Reset**.

[image]

4. Use Windows Compatibility List.

Open "Windows Edge".

Type "about:flags".

Click "Enter".

Check "Use Windows Compatibility List".

Restart the computer.

[image]

5. Try to update Windows updates.
6. Logon the laptop with another computer account, if we still have this problem, try reinstalling the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AMD's Virtual Super Resolution or NVIDIA's DSR (Dynamic Super Resolution), it may cause this kind of trouble.